# Is there a google analytics library with reporting functionality for android?

Tags: android, google-analytics-api

I am looking for a way to access Google Analytics reporting functionality on Android device.

An far as I can see, there is [just tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/) libriary for Google Analytics and Andoid. So my question is: **What is the way to get Google Analytics reports on the Android device?**

I was trying to use Java6 Google Analytics API installed by Google plugin for Eclipse, but was failed because of multiple errors, that seems to be related to different jars content for Java6 and its Android implementation.

Comment: Any reason why you are not considering Flurry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Google Analytics [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/). There's a [Java client library](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries) available which works on Android.

Comment: thanks! I thought there is no way to use GA api on android, but it obviously is.